Overriding escapeObjectName method from liquibase.database.core.PostgresDatabase. in Springboot
I am porting an old project that uses Liquibase to Spring Boot. The old project overrides the escapeObjectName method from the liquibase.database.core.PostgresDatabase class in order to return the object names unquoted. The reason for this is that we work with Postgres, and all names must be in lowercase.
Is it possible to do the same in Spring Boot?
Liquibase has to run on startup.
I have found a few solutions, but all of them suggest running Liquibase as a Spring Bean.
Of course I tried to extend the liquibase.database.core.PostgresDatabase but it never workded.
